# What would .shift do in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I am learning mongoDB and the below code will find the descendants of "Programming". However, I did not quite understand what would .shift do here.

```
    var descendants = [];
    var stack = [];
    var item = db.categories.findOne({_id:"Programming"});
    stack.push(item);
    while(stack.length>0){
    var current = stack.shift();
    for(let i=0; i<current.children.length;i++){
    var children = db.categories.findOne({_id:current.children[i]});
    stack.push(children);
    descendants.push(children._id);
    }
    }
    descendants;
```

Could anyone help me understand this functionality?

Answer (score 0):

the `stack.shift()` function shift the array `stack` one time to left. It says that the first element in the array removes from it, and returns to `current`.